# Include JavaScript code without packaging as a module

Tags: javascript, webpack

How do I require a JavaScript library that is not packaged as a UMD-compatible module (AMD, CommonJS) with webpack?

I don't want the library to pass through a loader. I just want it to be included in a `<script>` tag whenever it is required, and for webpack to manage this dependency.

I don't want to simply place it in a script tag in my `index.html`, because I want to take advantage of webpack's code-splitting, and only include it when necessary.

I've read about 'externals', I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it. The docs are not clear enough.

Thanks :)

---

### Updated question

Also this question is specifically about front-end libraries that only need to be included via a `<script>` tag to work.

Answer (score -1):

You can add amd support to your library and then load it with webpack.
Some links that can help you achieve are:

- http://ifandelse.com/its-not-hard-making-your-library-support-amd-and-commonjs/
- https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/1921

What is basically being done is that at the top of your library you can check whether it's a commonjs environment or an AMD environment. Accordingly you can export your library.

One example can be this ( taken from [1st link](http://ifandelse.com/its-not-hard-making-your-library-support-amd-and-commonjs/) )

```
(function (root, factory) {
  if(typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    // Now we're wrapping the factory and assigning the return
    // value to the root (window) and returning it as well to
    // the AMD loader.
    define(["postal"], function(postal){
      return (root.myModule = factory(postal));
    });
  } else if(typeof module === "object" && module.exports) {
    // I've not encountered a need for this yet, since I haven't
    // run into a scenario where plain modules depend on CommonJS
    // *and* I happen to be loading in a CJS browser environment
    // but I'm including it for the sake of being thorough
    module.exports = (root.myModule = factory(require("postal")));
  } else {
    root.myModule = factory(root.postal);
  }
}(this, function(postal) {
  // module code here....
  return myModule;
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to figure out how to include third-party front-end libraries that don't need to be packaged as modules. Isn't there a more straight forward way to do this without digging into the library's code?